# _curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR when running jenkins

Tags: bash, python, jenkins

I'm running [pg_activity](https://github.com/dalibo/pg_activity) through a bash script to simulate that pg_activity that can launch correctly without any issues.
Below is my script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash 

/soft/python3.7/bin/pg_activity <<EOF > /tmp/another_log_file141123.log 2>&1
h
q
q
EOF
```

The aim of my bash script is to emulate the run of `pg_activity`, then input a `h` plus `q` twice.

Through a terminal, it behaves correctly. Issue is I'm sending it through a Jenkins pipeline.

it gives me the following errors

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/soft/python3.7/bin/pg_activity", line 320, in main
    PGAUI.init_curses()
  File "/soft/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgactivity/UI.py", line 472, in init_curses
    self.__init_curses()
  File "/soft/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgactivity/UI.py", line 609, in __init_curses
    curses.cbreak()
_curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/soft/python3.7/bin/pg_activity", line 462, in <module>
    main()
  File "/soft/python3.7/bin/pg_activity", line 401, in main
    PGAUI.at_exit_curses()
  File "/soft/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgactivity/UI.py", line 696, in at_exit_curses
    curses.nocbreak()
_curses.error: nocbreak() returned ERR
```

All the options even the `--output` options give me the python traceback. Only option that I can use is the version one `--version` but that does not give me enough confidence, that `pg_activity` is working correctly.

Any clues or hints would be welcomed.